# QPrinter margin does not work as expected

Tags: c++, qt, qprinter

I am working on printing with Qt C++. But I found a problem that the margin does not work as expected. Here the QPrinter configuration I used.

```
QPrinter *pr = new QPrinter(QPrinterInfo::printerInfo("Canon iP2700 series"));
pr->setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
pr->setFullPage(true);
pr->setPageMargins(5, 5, 5, 5, QPrinter::Millimeter);
QTextDocument *d = new QTextDocument(this);
d->setHtml("<i>Try printing from QT</i>");
d->print(pr);
```

And the result margin is really far away from the edge (it should be 5mm), I also try to print it on real printer. And it seems the printer has internal margin, and the margin I set to the printer will be added to the internal margin.

In my issue, the internal margin is 20mm. So if i set the printer margin to 10mm, when it printed, the margin on paper is 30mm.

Is there anyone has experience about this? How the to make the margin works?

PS: I am using Qt 5.5 VC 2013.

Comment: It may be this Qt bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32987

Comment: It strange, the bug is 2013 and still no fix.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading little deep on the documentation. It says on that the QTextDocument will add 20mm margin when printed.

> By default a 2 cm margin is set around the document contents

And I need to set the page size before print it.